# HashiCorp Vault Mongo error

Tags: mongodb, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to run the default configuration for hashicorp and mongo but I can't complete the tutorial from here: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/mongodb.html.

It crashes here:

```
vault write database/config/mongodb \
    plugin_name=mongodb-database-plugin \
    allowed_roles="readonly" \
    connection_url="mongodb://admin:Password!@mongodb.acme.com:27017/admin?ssl=true"
```

`-bash: !mongodb.acme.com: event not found`

I have mongo installed and done correctly the `vault mount database`

Comment: Looks like a bash escaping problem with the !. See https://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to change from that command.

```
vault write database/config/mongodb \
    plugin_name=mongodb-database-plugin \
    allowed_roles="readonly" \ 
    connection_url="mongodb://admin:passwd@127.0.0.1:27017/admin"
```

`Admin:Password` has to be changed to the current admin:password credentials (keep in mind that mongo don't have any admin:password with a fresh installation).

`!@mongodb.acme.com` had to be changed to the ip of the machine where mongo is.

Finally had to disable the ssl `ssl=false` or removing it directly.